# access website with vhost, htaccess on windows

Tags: php, windows, apache, .htaccess, url

I have a website.
This website doesn't have index.php. For every request, i redirect via htaccess to a dir/file that includes the code to each page, based on the url. Everything works fine on localhost (and i access in my machine as "projetositeA/").
Now i wanted to access this website on my LAN with another device, to test the layout.
So  put on the vhost:

```
Alias /siteA "c:/wamp/www/sites/siteA/projeto"
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName projetositeA
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/sites/siteA/projeto"
    <Directory  "c:/wamp/www/sites/siteA/projeto/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

My htaccess is:

```
Options -Indexes            

ErrorDocument 400 /site/page
ErrorDocument 401 /site/page
ErrorDocument 403 /site/page
ErrorDocument 404 /site/page
ErrorDocument 408 /site/page

ErrorDocument 500 /site/page
ErrorDocument 502 /site/page
ErrorDocument 503 /site/page
ErrorDocument 504 /site/page
ErrorDocument 505 /site/page


RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(|inicio$|missao|servicos|blog|depoimentos|duvidas|contato|noticia)$   site/page.php
```

The structure of my directories are:

c:/wamp/www/sites/siteA/projeto/site/page.php

Every code on php inside .../site/

When i tried to access like this: 192.168.0.14/siteA it gives me "not found". Every link on this domain that i tried gives me the same.

I have another website with index. And when i put 192.168.0.14/siteB it works perfectly.

I think i have to redirect the /siteA to root, but i dont know how. The root is already "localhost".
What can i do??

Answer (score -1):

> ```
> Alias /siteA "c:/wamp/www/sites/siteA/projeto"
> ```

This `Alias` doesn't seem to make sense? Since the target of the `Alias` is the same as the document root, it would mean that accessing `http://projetositeA/` and `http://projetositeA/siteA` would return the same files - which I'm sure is not the intention?

> And when i put 192.168.0.14/siteA

However, when you access by the IP address you aren't using the specific vHost - it will likely default to the first one.

From the vHost you posted, to access "Site A" you should be using a URL of the form:

```
http://projetositeA/site/page
```

...as defined by the `ServerName` directive inside the `<VirtualHost>`.

?